# How to pass a url with appended # section to Twitter?

Tags: twitter, url-shorteners

Is possible to send URLs with "#" selector to Twitter ?

In other terms, can I generate a short url pointing to a specific section in my webpage ?

I've tried to pass the url but Twitter interpret what is after "#" selector as a twitter user.

I've also tried to use tinyurl.com APIs to generate a short URL for each section of y webpage, but it ignores "#" appended to urls...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the hash mark as "%23" in the URL for URL-shortening services and Twitter.

Example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign%23Computing

Comment: you are the best

Comment: does %23 work? According to this question, it doesn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633205/sharing-link-with-fragment-identifier-to-twitter

Comment: @ChrisBetti Testing confirms that *both* methods (`%23` and `#` literal) are now working w/Twitter's t.co shortening service - can't vouch for tinyurl though.

Answer (score 1):

Like http://bit.ly/fafQa9 goes to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Computing`? If you can’t do it directly through Twitter then I guess you’ll have to go via a URL shortening service and paste the link in.

Comment: Usually you want to use a shortener with Twitter since you only have 140 characters to work with.

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a special character in the Twitter world indicating a topic name so putting a # in a URL will cause issues and unintended results as twitter software will interpret that as a hash tag and try to hyperlink it to search results containing that tag. As mentioned above you'll want to use a URL shortener to work around this as it will obviously not have a # in the URL but instead redirect to the proper URL with the # included.

Comment: yeah but I've tried to create a short url with tinyurl.com and it ignores # and the appended arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL shortener like bquot.com, which allows linking to specific page section.